# Convert string to the list it describes

Tags: python

Say someone gives me a string like:

```
"[[A,B],[C,D]]"
```

and I want to extract the list it describes:

```
[[A,B],[C,D]]
```

How do I do this?

P.S.

A, B, C, D are just placeholders, they could be numeric values or strings.

Comment: `[[A,B],[C,D]]` is not valid Python. Can you clarify?

Comment: Are `A`, `B` etc. placeholders occupied by literal values, or are they some existing variable names, or something else?

Comment: Placeholders, it could be anything, numbers, string, etc.

Comment: Note, while this is possible you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this

Answer (score 5):

To prevent an `ValueError: malformed string` from being raised when passing the input directly to `ast.literal_eval`, `"`s need to be added around the characters in the string:

```
import ast, re
s = "[[A,B],[C,D]]"
new_s = ast.literal_eval(re.sub('\w+', '{}', s).format(*['"{}"'.format(i) for i in re.findall('\w+', s)]))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]
```

Comment: That's neat! Never seen that before.

Comment: Actually ast is enough, see my P.S., A,B,C and D are placeholders. Did not know about ast, need to learn, do you have a good link to its use?

Comment: @user See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for information specifically regarding `ast.literal_eval` or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for more about syntax parsing in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Based on `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` being numbers (`int`, or `float`) or strings (`str`), you can simply use:

```
l = eval("[[A,B],[C,D]]")
```

For example:

```
In [1]: l = eval("[[1,2],[3,4]]")

In [2]: l
Out[2]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]


In [3]: l = eval("[['Hello', 10],['bye', 100]]")

In [4]: l
Out[4]: [['Hello', 10], ['bye', 100]]

In [5]: l = eval("[[3.14, 1],['bye', 2.72]]")

In [6]: l
Out[6]: [[3.14, 1], ['bye', 2.72]]
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting on the difference between eval and ast.literal_eval?

Comment: @user, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) with several answers explaining the difference between `eval` and `ast.literal_eval()`, is it enough for you?